# html5 svg process png image

Tags: html, svg

i am studying html5's svg tag.

When I use the example from some website, it works:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
   <image xlink:href="http://developer.tizen.org/sites/all/themes/tizen_theme/logo.png" 
          width="224" height="74" />
</svg>
```

but when i change to my png image from my local files, it fails. what's wrong?

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
   <image xlink:href="subway.png" 
          width="250" height="442" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Are you seeing any errors in the Browser's Inspector?  Maybe, something like the image is not being loaded. Could the file this code is in and the image be in different folders?

Comment: Can you post a link to the site where you found this code?

Comment: We need more to go on.  Are these SVGs standalone ".svg" files, or are they inlined in an HTML page?